# Docker best practices: single process for a container

Tags: php, nginx, docker, virtual-machine, dockerfile

The Docker [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/) guide states that:

*"...you should only run a single process in a single container..."*

Should Nginx and PHP-FPM run in separate containers? Or does that mean that micro service architectures only run one service or "app" in a container?

Having these services in a single container seems easier to deploy and maintain.

Comment: I have recently started using Docker and come across the same query. I ended up having separate containers for each. I would be interested to find out here why this is 'best practice' though.

Comment: @DavidT Because it allows you to scale the service at the docker composition/ configuration level, without modifying configuration of the service itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the use case, you **can** run multiple processes inside a single container, although I won't recommend that.

In some sense it is even simpler to run them in different containers. Keeping containers small, stateless, and around a single job makes it easier to maintain them all. Let me tell you how my workflow with containers is in a similar situation.

So:

1. I have one container with nginx that is exposed to the outside world (:443, :80). At this level it is straightforward to manage the configurations, tls certificates, load balancer options etc.
2. One (or more) container(s) with the application. In that case a php-fpm container with the app. Docker image is stateless, the containers mount and share the volumes for static files and so on. At this point, you can at any time to destroy and re-create the application container, keeping the load-balancer up and running. Also, you can have multiple applications behind the same proxy (nginx), and managing one of them would not affect the others.
3. One or more containers for the database... Same benefits apply.
4. Redis, Memcache etc.

Having this structure, the deployment is modular, so each and every "service" is separated and logically independent from the rest of the system.

As a side effect, in this particular case, you can do **zero-downtime deployments** (updates) to the application. The idea behind this is simple. When you have to do an update, you create a docker image with the updated application, run the container, run all the tests and maintenance scripts and if everything goes well, you add the newly created container to the chain (load balancer), and softly kill the old one. That's it, you have the updated application and users didn't even notice it at all.

Comment: Very well answered. I love the idea of multiple app instances behind a nginx forward proxy. Although If im running say two applications (4x instances) how can i cross configure the nginx.conf file? is it possible to pass a config into the nginx container from PHP-APP-1 and PHP-APP-2 ?

Comment: Personally, I am defining explicitly the configuration of the nginx (that's an internal policy to do it explicitly). First of all, I am not altering nginx.conf for every application, but I have separate config files for each application in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled directory which is included into the nginx.conf. You can improvize and take the config files from the container. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This means process in the Linux/Unix sense of the word. That said, there's nothing stopping you from running multiple processes in a container, it's just not a recommended paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

We have found that we can run multiple services using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). It makes the architecture pretty easy, requiring only that you have an additional supervisor.conf file. For instance:

*supervisord.conf*

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:apache2]
command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"

[program:udpparser]
command=bin/bash -c "exec /usr/bin/php -f /home/www-server/services/udp_parser.php"
```

From Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 supervisor php5 php5-mysql php5-cli

RUN mkdir -p /var/lock/apache2 /var/run/apache2 /var/log/supervisor

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
ADD default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
ADD apache2.conf /etc/apache2/
ADD www-server/ /home/www-server/

EXPOSE 80 443 30089

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

As a ***best practice*** we only do this in cases where the services benefit from running together while all other containers are stand-alone micro-services.

Comment: Though this means you can run multiple processes using just one `CMD`, you still actually have multiple processes running in the same container. So does this not go against that best practice, or have I misunderstood? Even [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/using_supervisord/) suggest doing this. Stating *"In this example we’re going to make use of the process management tool, Supervisor, to manage* ***multiple processes*** *in our container."* - Which is confusing!

Comment: "Best practice" at a certain point is a matter of choice. I wouldn't manage more than three processes in *any* container and I would examine why we would need to do that closely. It is confusing (a lot of Docker can be that way) but in discussions with folks from Docker I have found that they support the use of Supervisor ***in cases where it makes sense*** to place multiple processes in one container.