# Running apache/php in Kubernetes/docker

Tags: php, apache, docker, kubernetes

Currently I am using `php:7.3-apache` docker image for running apache and I am experiencing a memory issue.

1. Even though I set up PHP maximum memory limit quite low (32MB), the container easily consume all memory of the container (600 MB) even though there is no traffic and single request can cause this.
2. Normally docker expects a single process running, however apache here forks several processes. So when the memory limit is reached, kubernetes wants to kill the Apache process, however it kills just some of the forks.

Would it be a good idea to force apache use a single process? I found such usage only for debug with `-X` parameters. Is apache even suitable for running in docker image because of these forks?

Comment: Did you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999865/docker-best-practices-single-process-for-a-container https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/  http://supervisord.org/?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Please can you specify environment you are working on ? Are you using specific tutorial ?